# is there a Hive/hcat property to export partitioned tables to a single file instead of a directory?

Tags: hive, hiveql, hcatalog, apache-tez

I am trying to export a table with partitions. By default, it generates number of files based on the number of partitions. Is there a property I can set to merge the files, what is the performance consideration for making this change.

Few of the properties I found around merging small files, but all them seem to work inside a partition.

```
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
set hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
set hive.merge.size.per.task=128000000;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000000;
```

I also don't have the option to write a separate concat code to append the files at the end.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly, you could do a `select * from table_name` and export the result into a file. This will have all the data along with the partition name in a separate columns.

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://quickstart:10000/default --quiet --outputformat=dsv --delimiterForDSV='|' --showHeader=false -e "select * from table_name" > output_file.csv
```

More on beeline output in the [official doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-OutputFormats).

I don't think merging all the files from partition is a good approach as it may lead to data corruption.